# Deselecting an item in collection view and removing that from an array not working

Tags: arrays, swift, uicollectionview

I am trying to select a cell and add the content of that cell into an array and then to be able to deselect a cell and remove that same object from the array. I've been struggling for a few days and still can't seem to get it work. Select and deselect functionality works, it's adding objects to the array but upon deselection, I don't know how to remove that same object from the array. How can I deselect the cell and remove that from the array?

This is my code:

```
    struct Friends {
    var friendName : String!
}

struct SelectedMembers {
    var selectedFriend : String!
}


    var friends = [Friends]()
    var selectedFriends = [SelectedMembers]()

        //MARK: Select multiple cells
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as? FriendsCell
        selectedCell.append(indexPath)
        cell?.contentView.backgroundColor = .red
        print("Friends are: \(String(describing: cell?.nameSurname.text!))")

        if (cell?.isSelected)! {
            print("this is selected...")
            var selection = SelectedMembers()
            selection.selectedFriend = friends[indexPath.item].friendName
            selectedFriends.append(selection)

            print(selectedFriends)

        }




    }

    //MARK: Deselect Multiple cells
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didDeselectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let deselectedCell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as? FriendsCell
        print(indexPath.row)
        if let index = selectedFriends.index(of: selectedFriends[indexPath.row]) {
            selectedFriends.remove(at: index)
        }

        if selectedCell.contains(indexPath) {
            selectedCell.remove(at: selectedCell.index(of: indexPath)!)
            deselectedCell?.contentView.backgroundColor = .white
            print(selectedCell)
        }


        print(selectedFriends)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this piece of code is the culprit.

> if let index = selectedFriends.index(of: selectedFriends[indexPath.row]) {selectedFriends.remove(at: index)}

For example, if you have 100 rows, and if you have selected 1, 10, 50 cells, your **selectedFriends** array contains only 3 objects, but when someone deselected the 50 the cell, in the above code you are trying to access selectedFriends[50]..so it is not proper.

> you don't need to maintain **selectedCell** array to keep track of selected/unselected indexes. Whenever a cell is selected you will get a callback in didSelecte and **only selected cells only can be deselected.**

place the below code in didDeselect()

```
let deselectedCell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as? FriendsCell
deselectedCell?.contentView.backgroundColor = .white
let friendName = friends[indexPath.item].friendName
var deselectedIndex:Int
for (index,value) in selectedFriends.enumerated() { if value.friendName == freindName { deselectedIndex = index }}
selectedFriends.remove(at:deselectedIndex}
```

> It is better to use Dictionary if your friend list is more, so you can avoid the for loop to find the deselected friend. Implement Equatable protocol instead of checking the only name if you go ahead with array implementation.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I am getting this error when for loop it's happening: "Expression type (SelectedMembers) it's ambiguous without more context". Also var deselectedIndex it's an integer?  var deselectedIndex = Int()? should I place it like this?

Comment: Hi Kumar! I still get this error : Binary operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'SelectedMembers' and 'String?' Don't worry I always mark the answers, it's just that I didn't get it to work yet.

Answer (score 1):

According to me, create a isSelected key in "SelectedMembers" object and change that key value for selected and unselected cell and after that reload the tableView.
And at last you will retrieve an array of selected cell by simple loop.

other wise use it

```
 extension SelectRecipeViewController: UITableViewDelegate {
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let product =  self.productList[indexPath.row]
    if arraySelectedProduct.contains(recipe) {
        let index = arraySelectedRecipes.index(of: recipe)
        arraySelectedProduct.remove(at: index!)
    } else {
        arraySelectedProduct.append(recipe)
    }
    tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: .none)
}
}
```